# Spy++ 32 and 64 bit doesn't allow for both to run simultaneously. Why?

Tags: winapi, message

I'm debugging a 32 bit port to 64 bit platform.  There's a bug causing issues with one of the windows not responding to a message properly on the 64 bit version only.  So I run them side by side and tried to use Spy++ on them.

Turns out that you can't use Spy++ 32 on a 64 bit application and vice versa.  Also turns out that you can't run both Spy++ 32 and 64 bit versions simultaneously.

What's this all about and how can I get around this issue.  Is there an equivalent that would intercept messages on both 32 and 64 bit versions?

Answer (score 3):

Spy uses message hooks to intercept the messages.  Message hooks must be in a DLL, and one cannot load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process (and vice versa).  As for not being able to run both versions simultaneously, I suspect it's because the hook DLLs use the same method to send to the app, so you can only have one app running.

Implementing a single interceptor would be quite difficult, for two reasons:

1. `SetWindowsHookEx` doesn't allow 32-bit apps to set hooks in 64-bit processes (and vice versa), so you'll need two exes (and two DLLs) to implement this, along with some IPC mechanism to communicate the results to a common host;
2. Hooks need to be fast (to minimize impact) and most IPC mechanisms would be too slow.

Comment: So in other words, the DLL used by Spy++ 32 and 64 bit is the same one?  Hmmmm, seems like that is an implementation error.

Comment: @Adrian No, Spy uses a separate DLL for 32 bit and 64 bit processes.

Comment: Then again, why would there be a problem running both simultaneously?

Comment: @Adrian See part 2. It's not an issue running the hooks simultaneously, it's an issue with communicating the results back to the host.

Comment: Back to the host computer?  So if there are 2 applications, one 32 and one 64 bit, running hooks, this would fail?  I feel that this can't be so.  Do you have any docs to back that up?

Comment: @Adrian 'Host' as in the app that installs the hooks.  This is getting a bit long for a comment thread, and should probably move somewhere else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38512/discussion-between-eric-brown-and-adrian)